# Cron won't stop code running when I execute job.stop()

Tags: node.js, cron

I am experimenting with [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) in node

I am posting using postman to get the below message to print to the console every 5 seconds.

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {

let job = new CronJob('*/5 * * * * *', function() {
  console.log('You will see this message every 5 second');
})

if(req.body.job === 'start'){
    job.start()
}else if(req.body.job === 'stop'){
    job.stop()
}
    res.send('done')
```

}

This works no problem

However, when I post

```
{
    "job": "stop"
}
```

from postman, the code keeps running.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to include job.stop() in the original post to postman

```
  if(req.body.job === 'start'){
    job.start()
    setTimeout(()=>{ 
      console.log('stop task')
      
      job.stop()

    }, 10000)
  }
```